# How to access a field of a referenced entity in a computed field?

Tags: entities

I would like to access a field of a referenced entity in a computed field.

For example: The content type A contains an entity reference field referencing the content type B; B has a "price" field. A has a computed field as well. In this field I would like to load the value of the "price" field from the referenced node.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Only, you have to add a Condition (in 'Elements') to the rule of the class "Entity has field", and then a whole bunch of the referenced fields of the entity will appear and will be available.

You'll have to create another Component to call it and add it another Condition of "Entity has field" of the same bundle you want to access.